# WCF Server Push connectivity test. Ping()?

Tags: wcf, callback, server-push, connectivity

Using techniques as hinted at in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.callbackcontract.aspx

I am implementing a ServerPush setup for my API to get realtime notifications from a server of events (no polling).  Basically, the Server has a RegisterMe() and UnregisterMe() method and the client has a callback method called Announcement(string message) that, through the CallbackContract mechanisms in WCF, the server can call.  This seems to work well.

Unfortunately, in this setup, if the Server were to crash or is otherwise unavailable, the Client won't know since it is only listening for messages.  Silence on the line could mean no Announcements or it could mean that the server is not available.

Since my goal is to reduce polling rather than immediacy, I don't mind adding a void Ping() method on the Server alongside RegisterMe() and UnregisterMe() that merely exists to test connectivity of to the server.  Periodically testing this method would, I believe, ensure that we're still connected (and also that no Announcements have been dropped by the transport, since this is TCP)

But is the Ping() method necessary or is this connectivity test otherwise available as part of WCF by default - like serverProxy.IsStillConnected() or something.  As I understand it, the channel's State would only return Faulted or Closed AFTER a failed Ping(), but not instead of it.

2) From a broader perspective, is this callback approach solid?  This is not for http or ajax - the number of connected clients will be few (tens of clients, max).  Are there serious problems with this approach?  As this seems to be a mild risk, how can I limit a slow/malicious client from blocking the server by not processing it's callback queue fast enough?  Is there a kind of timeout specific to the callback that I can set without affecting other operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach sounds reasonable, here are some links that may or may not help (they are not quite exactly related):

[Detecting Client Death in WCF Duplex Contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427926/detecting-client-death-in-wcf-duplex-contracts)
http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/08/performance-of-http-polling-duplex.html

Having some health check built into your application protocol makes sense.

If you are worried about malicious clients, then add authorization.

The second link I shared above has a sample pub/sub server, you might be able to use this code. A couple things to watch out for -- consider pushing notifications via async calls or on a separate thread. And set the sendTimeout on the tcp binding.

HTH

Comment: Thanks!  This is a good answer.  As this question has to do, in part, with opinions, I'd like to get a few more, so I'm leaving it open.  But +1 so far.

Comment: You can also mark the callback operations as "OneWay" to not worry about what clients do in their callback methods.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a WCF application and encountered a similar problem. My server checked clients had not 'plug pulled' by periodically sending a ping to them. The actual send method (it was asynchronous being a server) had a timeout of 30 seconds. The client simply checked it received the data every 30 seconds, while the server would catch an exception if the timeout was reached.

Authorisation was required to connect to the server (by using the built-in feature of WCF that force the connecting person to call a particular method first) so from a malicious client perspective you could easily add code to check and ban their account if they do something suspicious, while disconnecting users who do not authenticate.

As the server I wrote was asynchronous, there wasn't any way to really block it. I guess that addresses your last point, as the asynchronous send method fires off the ping (and any other sending of data) and returns immediately. In the SendEnd method it would catch the timeout exception (sometimes multiple for the client) and disconnect them, without any blocking or freezing of the server.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a publisher / subscriber service similar to the one suggested by Juval:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

This would allow you to persist the subscribers if losing the server is a typical scenario.  The publish method in this example also calls each subscribers on a separate thread, so a few dead subscribers will not block others...