# The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

[image: Game]

error occur: "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."

that error occured due to app.config?

have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: see to it if helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443390/communicationobjectabortedexception-communicationobjectfaultedexception-in-wcf

Comment: ok thanks i saw that but i have another error at that line also,error : "The address of the security token issuer is not specified. An explicit issuer address must be specified in the binding for target 'net.tcp://localhost:5054/player' or the local issuer address must be configured in the credentials." and then that error created...have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this error, event though no first-chance exception was appearing on the server, and in my case it was because the response I was receiving included 200k of bytes (a pdf); and I hadn't set up the appropriate settings in my config file to allow large sizes, and appropriate timeouts:

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IExampleService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

It would have been nice if the error messages had been more specific.

Obviously, my 2 gigabyte limit is not necessarily appropriate in your situation I would encourage readers to choose a value that is appropriate for your specific use case.

Comment: Yeah increasing my allowed message size fixed my issue with receiving a fault. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when you get an unhandled exception either in the server or the client. That client you have is not good anymore and you need to create a new one.

In case the error happened on the server side, you should be using fault exceptions (they don't fault the channel). You can also subscribe to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject.faulted.aspx) event to know exactly when it happened.

Comment: i also create that event and i create console application that why that error ocuured .have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

what can be the reason is that u use a service to get data from another program or whatever.  for example if u use a technicService version 1.2 ( see web.config) and and for example a billingService version 1.3( see web.config) now it can happen that your billing service corresponds with technicService 1.3 instead of 1.2 then you olso get this error