# Raising events in WCF server

Tags: wcf, events

I saw some discussions in SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739501/how-can-a-wcf-service-raise-events-to-its-clients) saying there's no such thing as events in WCF.
On the other hand, I was following [this tutorial](http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-Events.aspx) and got to the 'events' section.

Is the code in the tutorial considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not bad practice but those events will be used (consumed) on server (service) side host-process only (when service class/contract interface accessible directly). Standard WCF-clients don't know about those events which are not reflected in auto-generated client proxies.

But you can use service contract interface with events to constrain custom client proxies (aka service/server agents) if raw interface definition is accessible on client.