# Implementing a web service callback

Tags: c#, web-services, callback

I have a winforms C# desktop application. I have a polling web service to my server to retrieve messages as and when they come in.  Is there a way of implementing a callback web service from my desktop to the server instead of polling the web service? Is this what asynchronous web services are about?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a WCF Service Raise Events to its Clients?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739501/how-can-a-wcf-service-raise-events-to-its-clients)

Comment: Thanks for that link. So< I would have to use a WCF instead of web services? Thansk

Comment: What are you using today? When you mentioned web services and C#, I supposed you were talking about WCF. "web services" is a description, you can have a "web service" in almost any language and technology or framework.

Comment: Hi, yes I know all about wcf but I want to use a web service as I like the flexibility of it and I do not have to muck around with end-points,  I have not ruled it out I was just looking at keeping things simple.  What would be you opinion of calling a web service asynchronously, and it returns when it has a value from the server?  As soon as it has a message or/and times out it re-invokes that service? Just looking at all options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to achieve this: one the one Hand, you can start a request to the server with a very long timeout. Let the server wait for a new message (and assert that the request does not timeout on the Server side) and return the request once there is one. If the request times out, issue a new one. 
In WCF, there are some other techniques like [Duplex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) Services to solve this.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. I had considered that approach. I also looked into WCF but it seemed inflexible in terms of setting up its end-bindings (etc). Just really wanted to see what others ideas there were. thanks