# WCF net tcp service object has null event

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, events, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service implementing a service contract with only one method 'foo'.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Foo(MyEntity entity);
}
```

I'm implementing this interface with some added properties and an event.

```
internal class MyWCFService : IWCFService
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private ServiceHost WCFServiceHost { get; set; }

    internal MyWCFService()
    {
        NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

        WCFServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCFService), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61243") });

        WCFServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWCFService), tcpBinding, "MyWCFService");
    }

    internal void Start()
    {
        WCFServiceHost.Open();            
    }

    internal void Stop()
    {
        this.WCFServiceHost.Close(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
    }

    void IWCFService.Foo(MyEntity entity)
    {
        //Business logic...

        ThrowEvent(entity);
    }

    private void ThrowEvent(MyEntity entity)
    {
        if (this.MyEvent != null) //this.MyEvent is always null even though I'd successfully suscribe a function in another class
        {
            this.MyEvent(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

On another class **in the same server application**, I'm suscribing to 'MyEvent'.

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    internal MyWCFService TheService { get; set; } = new MyWCFService();

    public void Start()
    {
        this.TheService.MyEvent += FunctionThatDoesSomethingWithMyEntity;
        //Breakpoint here, this.TheService.MyEvent has 1 suscriber
        this.TheService.Start();
    }

    private void FunctionThatDoesSomethingWithMyEntity(MyEntity entity)
    {
         //More logic...
    }
}
```

The problem is that, even though I've checked with the debugger that the function *FunctionThatDoesSomethingWithMyEntity* has successfully suscribed to *MyEvent* in *OtherClass.Start()*, when the client calls the WCF service method *Foo*, *MyEvent* is null.

Furthermore, I noticed the following error while stopping at a breakpoint inside Foo: 
**error CS1061: 'MyWCFService' does not contain a definition for 'MyWCF' and no extension method 'MyWCF' accepting a first argument of type 'MyWCFService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
I believe that each time the clients call *Foo* a new MyWCFService object is created and therefore *MyEvent* is null, is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events don't work across WCF like you are expecting them to do.[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739501/how-can-a-wcf-service-raise-events-to-its-clients), might help you out though. Basically you need to use callbacks instead.

Edit: Since you clarified and are trying to bind to the event not over WCF, but in another class on the server/WCF project, you are correct in your assumption that each instance of the WCF client created spawns a new class and therefore loses the event binding. I can't promise it would work as I can't test it at the moment, but you could try making the event "static" so it wouldn't get created with each new class instance.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the event is not for the client, *AnotherClass* is hosted on the server.

Comment: Edited to hopefully help ya out.

Comment: Ok, let me try it out and I'll come back.